# Find the smallest word in a string in Java

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to find the smallest word in a user entered string. This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String myText = sc.next();
    String[] myWords = myText.split(" ");
    int shortestLength,shortestLocation;

    shortestLength=(myWords[0]).length();

    shortestLocation=0;

    for (int i=1;i<myWords.length;i++) {
        if ((myWords[i]).length() < shortestLength) {
            shortestLength=(myWords[i]).length();
            shortestLocation=i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(myWords[shortestLocation]);
}
```

If I entered `"SMALLEST WORD SHOULD BE A"`, the output should be `A` but it just gives me the first word of the string. Any ideas?

Comment: Glad you found your answer! Remember to read the Javadocs, and you would've discovered you were using the wrong method :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your algorithm is fine, but instead of using [`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29):

```
String myText = sc.next();
```

Which will only read a single token, i.e., the *first* word, use [`nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29), which will read the *entire* line:

```
String myText = sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I more quick question: if I put a number into the string it will give me the number as the shortest value. Is there anyway to disregard numbers put into the string so that it only reads letters and words?

Comment: @Eric: Yes, to test if a String is a number, you can use `if (myWords[i].matches("\\d+")) { // number }`. `\\d+` matches one or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

To take the full string you have to use the method

```
sc.nextLine();
```

thus it will take the complete string.